# oracle missing expression when using Max

Tags: oracle

This project requires to gather data from the pass 27 months, which will let to 2 conditions:

3 months(this year) + 12 year(previous year) + 12 years(previous previous year)
1 months(this year) + 12 year(previous year) + 12 years(previous previous year) + 2 (previous3 year) or 2 months(this year) + 12 year(previous year) + 12 years(previous previous year) + 1 (previous3 year)
I need to add a condition/column to data called 'date condition', for condition 1, only show this year and previous year's data (3 + 12 + 12) months, for condition 2, shows this year and previous year and previous previous year's data(1/2 + 12 + 12 + 1/2) months.

This condition was used to be as a calculated field in tableau, but the performance is too slow, so I want to filter it on data level. I wrote the code as below but receive error 936: missing expression

```
SELECT * FROM DDS_MQC_QAP_VW 
WHERE (INSP_YEAR IS NULL  
AND INSP_RESULT_REASON_DESC NOT LIKE '%On hold%'
AND INSP_RESULT_REASON_DESC NOT LIKE '%Aborted%'
)
OR
(
(
INSPECTION_DATE BETWEEN 
ADD_MONTHS(LAST_DAY(
ADD_MONTHS( (SELECT MAX(INSPECTION_DATE) AS MAX_DATE FROM DDS_MQC_QAP_VW) -26,))+1,-1)
AND (SELECT MAX(INSPECTION_DATE) AS MAX_DATE FROM DDS_MQC_QAP_VW)
)
AND INSP_RESULT_REASON_DESC NOT LIKE '%On hold%'
AND INSP_RESULT_REASON_DESC NOT LIKE '%Aborted%'
)
```

related data:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move comma to another place:

```
ADD_MONTHS( (SELECT MAX(INSPECTION_DATE) AS MAX_DATE FROM DDS_MQC_QAP_VW) -26,))+1,-1)
                                                                             ^
                                                                            here

ADD_MONTHS( (SELECT MAX(INSPECTION_DATE) AS MAX_DATE FROM DDS_MQC_QAP_VW), -26))+1,-1)
```

Comment: receive: invalid numbers of arguments

Comment: Aha; actually, you should move it back, in front of -26.